# Nancyfx executes the route but does not return a result. (Running on Raspberry pi Mono)

Tags: mono, response, raspberry-pi, nancy

Im currently running Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5) on my raspberry pi. I compiled the nancyfx monorelease configuration from master branch.

The application starts as expected

```
Nancy now listening - navigating to http://localhost:8888/nancy/. 
Press enter to stop
```

I then run a test as follows

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ wget  http://localhost:8888/nancy/
--2013-04-13 06:39:12--  http://localhost:8888/nancy/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8888... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

This will never complete. It just sits there.

I have added some logging and I can see that it processes the route action on the module but it never seems to return the http response.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a way to add more exception catching?

The following revealed nothing.

```
 public class LoggingErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    private readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggingErrorHandler));

    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }

    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        object errorObject;
        context.Items.TryGetValue(NancyEngine.ERROR_EXCEPTION, out errorObject);
        var error = errorObject as Exception;
        _logger.Error("Unhandled error", error);
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this - what is it you're returning? When you create the NancyHost you can provide a HostConfiguration object, and one of the properties on that is [UnhandledExceptionCallback](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Hosting.Self/HostConfiguration.cs#L26) which may shed some light on what's going wrong.